# How to float <p> to bottom of a <div> when you can't use position:relative and position:absolute

Tags: css

I'd like to float a `<p>` to the bottom of a `<div>`, but as far as I can tell, I can't set the parent `<div>` to `position:relative` or `position:absolute` without mucking up my layout, which uses the Susy framework for Compass.

How else can I do this?

Relevant HTML is:

```
<header>
  <div class='grid'>
    <div class='logo'>
      <img src='/images/logo3.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='tagline'>
      <p>Fast Facts About Your Website, Your Competition, And Best Practice</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Relevant CSS is:

```
header {
  clear: both;
}

.grid .logo {
  width: 30.43478%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4.34783%;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 3.75em;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid .tagline {
  width: 65.21739%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0;
  #margin-left: -3.75em;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand from your question you need `<p>` below your `logo` so clear your float after the `logo` `div` [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YdjqJ/)

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class='tagline'>
  <p>Fast Facts About Your Website, Your Competition, And Best Practice</p>
</div>
```

And why are you using floating widths? does it need to be so accurate? and why `display: inline;` in `.logo` and `.tagline`